# Measurement of marine propeller pitch

Tags: measurement, encoder, linear

I have a small project that I'm trying to figure the cheapest and most reliable method for. I. Wanting to measure various points along an outboard motor propeller to gauge the exact pitch to be able to make modifications. I need the difference between the leading edge and trailing edge measurements of each blade to gauge the amount of displacement, and then also measure the degree of rotation for these points so I can then measure pitch. I've looked at laser measurement but these are very expensive. And I've been having a look at LVDT but there are s many types and I'm unsure how I then get the information out of them. I wouldn't mind being able to read a display or have direct input to PC via USB. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you going to do this once for one or twice, or are you going to be making these measurements over and over again?

Comment: I'll be measuring multiple radii (0.6, 0.7, 0.8) for each blade where each propeller has 4 blades. I have quite a few propellers to measure and after making modifications I'd be measuring them again.

Comment: Two thoughts that come to mind are to build a probing machine based on a scaled up DIY 3d printer extrusion-and-steppers mechanism (though make sure to probe in a consistent direction to deal with backlash) possibly adapted from purely cartesian to polar coordinates given your radial object of interest, or else do a liquid-immersion or line-laser type of scanning with a camera.  Both have a number of challenges...

Comment: Why can't you use a ruler and a piece of string and what is the relevancy of this question to EE?

Comment: LVDT is the way to go. It is robust and reliable, for marine environment you need something like that. Then you make a look up table: governor displacement vs. pitch, then you can compute pitch each time you want.

Comment: I would be looking at something based on trammels to fit to the leading and trailing edges simultaneously, then measuring the angle between trammel arm and propshaft.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to carry out these measurements on a bench rather than under water ...

A common method for machine vision applications to measure heights in a cost effective manner is to use a laser line-scan to generate a line across the surface to be measured. An off-axis camera is used to view the line.

[image]

*Figure 1. A 3D vision application using a laser line generator and a 2D camera.*

The result is shown in Figure 1. The height of the pixel on the image relative to the base-line is proportional to the height of the object relative to the background.

As with all vision applications the system does present some difficulties in calibration and elimination of lens aberration.

A simpler method would be to make a stand for a laser distance sensor and a turntable for your propeller. I can't find any with USB interface but there are plenty of industrial types with 0 - 10 V analog out that you should be able to interface with a USB voltmeter of some sort.

[image]

*Figure 2. [Omron HS-ZL](https://www.ia.omron.com/products/family/3175/) range of sensors is one of many.*

One advantage of this is a visible spot so you know exactly where you're measuring and it's non contact so you have little mechanical work to do.

Add a protractor to your turntable for reference and make the sensor slide radially at a fixed height above the turntable. With a reference point for the tip of the prop you should be able to quickly run a series of measurements at at set of angles and radii.

[image]

*Figure 3. Prop measurement system.*